# How do I print a decimal number from a string in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, string, web-scraping, decimal

I'm trying to print the first decimal number from a string 'rating'.

The code is as follows:

```
rating = soup.find("span", attrs={"class", "a-icon-alt"}).get_text().strip()
print(rating)
```

which gives the output:

```
4.3 out of 5 stars
```

I want the output to be:

```
4.3
```

But if I use the code:

```
rating = soup.find("span", attrs={"class", "a-icon-alt"}).get_text().strip()[0]
print(rating)
```

I get the output as:

```
4
```

I need the decimal number to be displayed. How do I do that?

I hope the question is clear.

Comment: Change `strip()` to `split()` in your second snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You are just taking the first character of the string `"4.3 out of 5 stars"` you need to split it by spaces and then take the first element.

```
>>> "4.3 out of 5 stars".split(" ")[0]
'4.3'
```

So your final solution would be:

```
rating = soup.find("span", attrs={"class", "a-icon-alt"}).get_text().strip().split(" ")[0]
```